# Click function not working after switching between blocks

Tags: jquery

I have an application that renders a block for every order number. Every order number has their details below, now I want to add a manual check to if the order detail has been picked yes or no.

This works fine, but whenever I move over to another order, the previous one I have clicked something on does not work anymore.

I also get returned 2 lines in my console log after I clicked on a second order.

I think it is saving the $(this) function I clicked, but i don't know how to fix it.
Code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".checkenBon").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).parent().find('.checkenBonCijfer').val());
    if($(this).parent().find('.checkenBonCijfer').val() == '1') {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("bgblue");
        $(this).parent().find('.checkenBonCijfer').val(0);  
        $(this).find('img').attr("src", "img/check_unchecked.png");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().addClass("bgblue");
        $(this).parent().find('.checkenBonCijfer').val(1);
        $(this).find('img').attr("src", "img/check_checked.png");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The value for `$(this)` inside the ready function seems like it's going to be the jQuery object. If that's your actual code, I don't see why you're writing it this way

Comment: Oops, I've written that part of the code wrong (in front of the .click). I restored it in my code.

Comment: Please include the relevant html and jquery so we can reproduce the problem.